# Python3 Tkinter and Pillow: How to rotate an image while it is on a canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to move a turtle around a canvas by clicking on the canvas, and the turtle should point in the direction it is moving. The moving part works, but the rotate function causes the image to become distorted and mangled.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

I have a class that adds an image of a turtle to a canvas:

```
class TurtleImage:
    """
    A Turtle image that will be placed on the canvas that is given in the ctor.
    The turtle can be moved around the canvas with the move() method.
    """

    def __init__(self, canvas : Canvas):
        self.__turtle_file : str = self.__find_file("turtle_example/turtle.png")
        self.__canvas = canvas
        self.__pilImage : PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile = PILImage.open(self.__turtle_file)
        self.__pilTkImage : ImageTk.PhotoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.__pilImage)
        self.__turtle_id : int = canvas.create_image(100,100, image=self.__pilTkImage)
        self.__is_moving = False
```

This class also has a method to animate the turtle moving around the canvas. It moves the turtle by 1 pixel in the x direction, y direction, or both, and then scehdules itself to be called again after a time delay determined by the speed parameter. It also should rotate the turtle so it is pointing in the right direction:

```
def move(self, dest_x : int, dest_y :int, speed : float = 0.1):
    self.__is_moving = True
    delay_ms = math.floor(1/speed)
    current_x, current_y = self.__canvas.coords(self.__turtle_id)

    delta_x = 1 if current_x < dest_x else -1 if current_x > dest_x else 0
    delta_y = 1 if current_y < dest_y else -1 if current_y > dest_y else 0
    angle = math.atan2(delta_y,delta_x)

    self.__rotate(angle)

    if (delta_x, delta_y) != (0, 0):
        self.__canvas.move(self.__turtle_id, delta_x, delta_y)

    if (current_x, current_y) != (dest_x, dest_y):
        self.__canvas.after(delay_ms, self.move, dest_x, dest_y, speed)
    else:
        self.__is_moving = False
```

Because the canvas does not have the ability to rotate its objects, I must replace the object with a rotated version of itself:

```
def __rotate(self, angle : float):
    self.__pilImage = self.__pilImage.rotate(angle)
    self.__pilTkImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.__pilImage)
    self.__replace_image(self.__pilTkImage)

def __replace_image(self, new_image : ImageTk.PhotoImage):
    self.__canvas.itemconfig(self.__turtle_id, image = new_image)
```

The moving around works fine, but the rotate function causes the image to become distorted and mangled, and it gets worse every time it is called.

Can you tell me why this isn't working, and what I need to do to fix it?

Here's a screenshot of said turtle, before and after rotating:

[image] [image]

Comment: Are you going to share the original turtle image? And show us how a *"mangled"* turtle looks?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I'll edit and upload screenshots tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I've found the sollution, I have to reopen the file:

```
def __rotate(self, angle : float):
    self.__pilImage = PILImage.open(self.__turtle_file)
    self.__pilImage = self.__pilImage.rotate(angle)
    self.__pilTkImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.__pilImage)
    self.__replace_image(self.__pilTkImage)
```

I don't know why though.